# Adjusting date format, changing seems to hide code?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datetime

I am attempting to adjust the date format on my Wordpress theme to read e.g "20th Jan" rather than the full date.

I have adjusted the code as such according to the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time):

```
<time datetime="<?php the_date( 'j, S, M' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> </time>
```

According to the codex this should give 17, th, Jan.

Odd thing is, this does show up in the code when I view page source or inspect, but doesn't show up in view anywhere. Inspected code looks like:

```
<time datetime="17, th, Jan" pubdate=""> </time>
```

So it seems it's generating the right code but then not outputting it. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
<time datetime="<?php the_date( 'j, S, M' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> </time>
```

should be this:

```
<time datetime="<?php the_date( 'j, S, M' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date( 'j, S, M' ); ?> </time>
```

You are not passing the argument to the 2nd call to `the_date()` that is the one that will show up in view, the other is being output as an attribute which would not show up visibility.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Apologies this is my first time working with PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Along with passing the parameters in the seconds call of the_date() to format the date as you asked it would be

```
the_date('jS, M'); // output 20th, Jan

<time datetime="<?php the_date( 'jS, M' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date('jS, M'); ?> </time>
```

Comment: can you explain where the first part of this code goes? I copied this in but it does not work.

Comment: Sorry that was just showing what that function would out put.